# cannot edit magento pdf font size

Tags: php, magento, pdf

I need to increase the font size of magento pdfs. I read that I can edit the _setFontRegular method of abstract class so I copied /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php to /app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php, but no matter what changes I do in the file nothing changes in my invoice pdf. Only for testing purposes I tried to edit this line in the insertOrder method of the Abstract.php

```
Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Date: ')
```

with this:

```
Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ordersssss Date: ')
```

But my invoice pdf still has 'Order' instead of 'Orderssss', so my modification are not being read. Path in local folder is the same as it is in the Mage folder, I checked. If I copy and try to edit another pdf-related file such as Invoice.php, I can see my modification in the pdf, so it's only the Abstract.php that I cannot modify.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed, or core over-rides that are taking this method over?  Search your code base for `function insertOrder`

Comment: You're right. When I grepped the function to check it I forgot to add the recoursive option! Now I checked again I can see the custom module that is overriding insertOrder, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll have an extension that is implementing this abstract class - and therefore the (fallback) you're editing isn't the correct bit of code :)